# How do I remove the tagline from my header?

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

How do I comment out the tagline in my header.php?

I'm using the 2014 theme and attempting to follow the meta tag instructions in the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress). To generate a 'description' meta tag, it instructs you to add the description to the tagline. But this tagline is displayed at the top of each window/tab in which my webpage is open (along with my site name). To hide the tagline, WordPress advises to "remove or comment out the tag in the header area." I'm having trouble doing this. What exactly do I comment out in my header.php? I don't see anything in the header with the words 'tagline' or 'description.' I'm using a child theme FYI.

Here is my header.php

```
<?php /**  * The Header for our theme  *  * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">  *  * @package WordPress  * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen  * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0  */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<!--[if IE 7]>
 <html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> 
<![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]> 
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <![endif]--> 
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8) ]>
<!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <head> 
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
<title>
<?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
</title> 
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"> 
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>"> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script> 
<![endif]--> 
<?php wp_head(); ?> 
</head>
 <body <?php body_class(); ?>> 
<div id="page" class="hfeed site"> 
<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<div id="site-header">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">     
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
</a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner"> 
<div class="header-main"> 
<h1 class="site-title">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
</h1> 
<div class="search-toggle"> 
<a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text">
<?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?>
</a> 
</div> 
<nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation"> <button class="menu-toggle">
<?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></button> 
<a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?>
</a> 
<!-- <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?> --> 
</nav> 
</div>
<div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper hide"> 
<div class="search-box">
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
</div>  

</header><!-- #masthead -->     <div id="main" class="site-main">
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your header.php?

Comment: I'm trying.  The code is too long (by ~1600 characters) to fit in this comment field.  And when I try to edit my original post to include the code, only a few lines are added and the rest truncated.  Any ideas how to do this?  Maybe create a new post?

Comment: My code isn't properly formatted for some reason.  I'll work on that and post here if I can.

Comment: OK I inserted the content of my header.php into my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's inside `/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php`, in the function `twentyfourteen_wp_title()` called by the filter hook `wp_title`.

To modify this, in your child theme `/themes/child-theme/functions.php`, you can remove the original filter and add your own:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_stuff' );

function remove_parent_stuff()
{
    remove_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentyfourteen_wp_title', 10 );
    add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_child_wp_title', 10, 2 );
}

function my_child_wp_title( $title, $sep ) 
{
    // ADAPT the original 2014 function to your needs
    return 'Hello, world!';
}
```

And to add a meta description, use the following action hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_child_description' );

function my_child_description()
{
    echo '<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum lorem" />' . "\r\n"; // \r\n makes a line break, it has to be with double quotes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll give that shot.  Follow up question:  what happens when the 2014 theme is updated?  Will I have to manually re-copy the parent functions.php file and make this same modification?  If so, is there a way around that?  i.e. is there a way that this modification will be auto-applied to any new functions.php when the theme is updated?

Comment: You will add it on your **child theme**, the updates on the parent won't have any effect on your custom code.

Comment: Ah ok.  So to confirm, I can have a small functions.php file in my child theme that contains *only* the code you recommended above.  That code will override the corresponding code from the parent functions.php.  Similar (exactly?) to style.css.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think you missed the part `themes/YOUR-CHILD-THEME/functions.php` ;)